# Mac eclipse JavaFX no option to create a css or fxml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

i installed the plugin e(fx)clipse but i don't know how to add a css file to my package. i right click and there is no option of .css or .fxml files as compared to netbeans. Can anybody tell me what am I missing over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FXML, you can do "File" -> "New" (or right-click and "New") -> "Other" (or CMD-N to get this far), then expand JavaFX and you have the option for new FXML document.

For CSS, if you also have the web tools platform plugin (which I think is standard with Eclipse for JEE but not for Eclipse for JSE), do the same and expand "Web" and there is a CSS option. Otherwise you can just expand "General" and choose "File". If you need an additional plugin that edits CSS files, something like [Web Developer Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0) should work (though it might issue warnings for JavaFX-CSS properties that are in general not web-CSS properties; I just live with those warnings).

Comment: what will i have to do to have the css option if i don't want to go with the file @James_D

Comment: @IshanSrivastava Install Web Developer Tools: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0

Comment: To edit JavaFX CSS you only need e(fx)clipse it has a special editor for JavaFX. Just create a text-file ending in .css and the editor will open